# Is there any way to get this Xml Scheme creating a DataSet in C# or VB.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, vb.net, dataset

I would like to use the Dataset WriteXml method to have this xml schema... is it really possible to create a dataset with datatable to get this xml? I can't complete the nested objects part (Objects and Obj), please, any idea?

XML Scheme

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MyDatasetName>
<TblDef>
    <Field1>1</Field1>
    <Field2>9</Field2>
    <Objects>
        <Obj>
            <FieldA>123</FieldA>
            <FieldB>123</FieldB>
            <FieldC>123</FieldC>
        </Obj>  
        <Obj>
            <FieldA>456</FieldA>
            <FieldB>456</FieldB>
            <FieldC>456</FieldC>
        </Obj>
    </Objects>
</TblDef>
</MyDatasetName>
```

I share with yours my current code:

```
        Dim dsResult As New DataSet("MyDatasetName")
    Dim dr As DataRow
    Dim dt As New DataTable("TblDef")

    dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Field1", Type.GetType("System.String")))
    dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Field2", Type.GetType("System.String")))
    dr = dt.NewRow()
    dr("Field1") = "1"
    dr("Field2") = "9"
    dt.Rows.Add(dr)
    dsResult.Tables.Add(dt)

    Dim dtObjects As New DataTable("Obj")
    dtObjects.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("FieldA", Type.GetType("System.String")))
    dtObjects.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("FieldB", Type.GetType("System.String")))
    dtObjects.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("FieldC", Type.GetType("System.String")))

    For index = 1 To 3

        Dim drObj As DataRow
        drObj = dtObjects.NewRow()
        drObj("FieldA") = "test " + index.ToString()
        drObj("FieldB") = "test"
        drObj("FieldC") = "test"
        dtObjects.Rows.Add(drObj)
    Next

    dsResult.Tables.Add(dtObjects)
```

Only I have this xml..however, I need that all the nodes called "Obj" are contained inside a parent called "Objects". (Please look at first xml scheme).

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<MyDatasetName>
  <TblDef>
    <Field1>1</Field1>
    <Field2>9</Field2>
  </TblDef>
  <Obj>
    <FieldA>test 1</FieldA>
    <FieldB>test</FieldB>
    <FieldC>test</FieldC>
  </Obj>
  <Obj>
    <FieldA>test 2</FieldA>
    <FieldB>test</FieldB>
    <FieldC>test</FieldC>
  </Obj>
  <Obj>
    <FieldA>test 3</FieldA>
    <FieldB>test</FieldB>
    <FieldC>test</FieldC>
  </Obj>
</MyDatasetName>
```

Comment: "Field1" and "Field2" are as columns? and "Objects" is the data section? and "Obj" determines the values of columns in 3 rows(I mean you want to save all records on column 1 and then save the next column data)?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)